# Windows API, C++ standard library, VS runtime library, which one should I use?

Tags: c++, windows

As you can see from the title, I'm talking about programming on Windows with C++. When I learned C++ I only knew C++ standard libraries like `fstream`, but I see few uses of these on Windows. The Win32 API or MFC are more used. And I read some books like 'Windows Via C/C++', a lot of VS runtime libraries are used. It's quite confusing for me to learn so much.

I think the C++ standard library is more user-friendly. API and runtimes looks dizzy. The code (compared with C#) is so ugly to me... But I dare not use standard libraries because I'm afraid of been considered unprofessional...

So what is the best practice for programming on Windows?

Comment: Using the standard library is not unprofessional at all. In fact, using Windows-only API is plain silly, since you would be forever bound to Windows, while there are wonderful other libraries that do the same thing and are cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are targeting and the problems that you need to solve.

But a few things to bear in mind:

- There is likely no way to avoid using the Win32 API if you want to do anything other than write very simple console applications on windows.
- You can and should wrap the Win32 API in a C++ friendly manner, think RAII to deal with handles and resources, and wrappers which simplify the API and convert error codes into exceptions, etc.
- MFC is pretty horrible, especially if you like writing nice modern C++, but sometimes it's the easiest way to do a GUI.
- The VS runtime libraries sometimes provide functionality that is useful, see my suggestion re Win32 API, you likely just need to wrap these up.

Comment: Disagree with both the first and third point. Qt lets you write fancy apps without touching the Win32 API, and it's easier than MFC.

Comment: MSalters, fair enough though, IMHO, he wasn't asking for MORE choice in extra libraries. There are, of course, many other ways to use the Win32 API without explicitly calling the functions yourself and many ways to do GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is necessary a versus here. For any app you need different kind of Api: "Os Api" , "Gui Api" and "Runtime Api"

**Os Api** (sockets/ File system/threads)
First choice would be to use directly Windows API, but a better approach is to use a library like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) that wraps this. This way you app will run on (almost) any platform with no effort and you save precious time in the future (even if you are not targeting other os now).

**Runtime Api**
I will go for C runtime as is more portable. Allfunctions are also provided by Windows but there are few reasons to use them. I can see only one now: If you have a small amount of runtime api calls and you don;t want to be dynamically depended (link with runtime) and linking statically will make your binary large with no benefit.

**Gui Api**
here it depends on what you are looking/ know. If you are prolific with and Api, try to use that one.
Direct Api - for advanced customization.
MFC/WTL - Wrappers over the Direct Api. Simpler to use for classic issues but as your requirements are stranger and stranger using Direct Api calls becomes more simple.
WinForm/WTL - if you have knowledge you can have a managed gui and a unmanaged backend.

Hope it helps